# RollerCoaster Tycoon Platinum Windows To Mac

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

I have the Game RollerCoaster Tycoon for Windows/PC. I was wondering that now I have a Mac, if I can somehow take that game and put it on Steam, and play on my Mac, SO.. I went on Steam and went to "ADD A GAME" then "ACTIVATE A PRODUCT ON STEAM" because RollerCoaster Tycoon is on Steam, then I went to the box and couldn't find an Activation Code? Is there one? Or Where do I get one? Or am I going to need to buy the game over again?

Comment: *Which* RCT do you have? RCT1, RCT3 or RCT3 Platinum? You need to specify the exact title, because only RCT3 Platinum is on Steam, and even then not all retail copies may be registered with Steam.

Comment: And even if it can be registered on Steam, there's no guarantee there's a Mac version for it.

Comment: @fbueckert [RCT3](http://store.steampowered.com/app/2700/?snr=1_7_15__13) is on Steam and labeled as SteamPlay for Windows and Mac

Answer (score 2):

The only Roller Coaster Tycoon game on Steam is [Roller Coaster Tycoon 3](http://store.steampowered.com/app/2700/?snr=1_7_15__13) so I will assume that is the game in question.

Per [this list](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601) you cannot activate Roller Coaster Tycoon 3 via a CD key.  You will need to purchase it from Steam.  I would suggest waiting for the next time it is on sale, since that will likely sell it at 50-75% off.

Based on your OS, you might be able to run the game disc using [Boot Camp](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5639).